# Exchange 2010 Delay Message Based on outbound recipients

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010

I have been wondering whether it is possible to delay message sending if a user sends to more than a defined number of external users.

I have investigated message throttling and transport rules in particular the send connector but haven't really found anything suitable.

The aim is to que messages for a set period of time if the criteria is met allowing time to delete from the que if needed. If possible I would like to apply this queing to users within a AD group.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to manually create some delay within the Exchange queues?

In my research, I didn’t find a way to do this. As I know, it could control when the message is sent within Outlook client.

Comment: Hi yes that's exactly what I am trying to do but only if a email has more than X external recipients.

Comment: I actually can't find anything myself and have been looking for a few days now....

Comment: I’m afraid there isn’t a way to manually create the delay. If you want to decide whether the message is to be sent or rejected, I think you could create a rule “send a message to a moderator…” to do approval.